# Convert String to date format with contains characters month

Tags: java, string, date, struts

Good day,

Please correct me if my title and question is not correct.

Normally I just convert a String to a date format all in numeric, example :

`mm/dd/yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd` as `01/02/2000` to `2000-02-01`

or any other style/pattern.

I am thinking can I convert it to a date format with contains of characters month or not, example :

`mm/dd/yyyy` to `dd-MMM-yyyy` as `10/09/2013` to `09-Oct-2013`

Which is the month no longer display in numeric, but in alpha.

I am work in Java, Struts framework.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Have you looked into http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps. You can choose multiple patterns which can be found at link below.  Here is an example how to use it

[Multiple patterns can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#month)

```
 final String OLD_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy";

 final String NEW_FORMAT = "yyyy/MMM/dd";

 // August 12, 2010
 String oldDateString = "12/08/2010";
 String newDateString;

 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
 Date d = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
 sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
 newDateString = sdf.format(d);
```

`

Comment: Thanks Bhanu. But I not really do not know how do I put my input? For example my input is `10/09/2013`. and my desired output is `09-Oct-2013` .